# View wont update but the URL does in React Router V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using **react router V6** and have been following this tutorial for routing setup: https://blog.logrocket.com/react-router-v6/
but the view won't update when I click on the links in navigation menu.

visiting `localhost:3000/Crime` renders right component.
visiting `localhost:3000`/ renders right component.

but when clicking on the links, the view won't get updated, but the url path does.

**GameComponent:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import Component from 'react-dom';
import SideBarRight from "./components/game/sideBarRight.jsx";
import SideBarLeft from "./components/game/sideBarLeft.jsx";
import Crime from "./components/game/crime.jsx";

import "./gameComponent.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class GameComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { color: "red" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        data testing:
        <Router>
          <nav style={{ margin: 10 }}>
            <Link to="/" style={{ padding: 5 }}>
              Home
            </Link>
            <Link to="/crime" style={{ padding: 5 }}>
              Crime
            </Link>
          </nav>
          <Route path="/" element={<SideBarRight />} />
          <Route path="/crime" element={<Crime />} />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GameComponent;
```

**Crime component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import Component from 'react-dom';
import "./../../gameComponent.css";

class Crime extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      color: "red",
      user: {
        cash: 0,
        bank: 0,
        weapon: "",
        username: "test",
        locationname: "Bankok",
        defence: 0,
      },
      rankbar: { rankpercent: 50, rank: "Mafia" },
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <span>crimeday</span>;
  }
}

export default Crime;
```

**Sidebar**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import Component from 'react-dom';
import "./../../gameComponent.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

class SideBarLeft extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { color: "red" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content_sidebar">
        <div className="header">
          <span>Computerbar1</span>
        </div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Clear</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/crime">Crime</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SideBarLeft;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For react-router v5:**

Use [Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) and [exact](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool):

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<SideBarRight />} />
  <Route exact path="/crime" element={<Crime />} />
</Switch>
```

`Switch` renders the first child `Route` or `Redirect` that matches the location. And when `exact` is `true`, the route will only match if the path matches the `location.pathname` exactly.

You should not use `exact` when your route has nested child routes, for example, if you have `/crimes/summary` or `/crimes/details` etc as child routes inside `/crimes`.

---

If you are using [**react-router v6**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router/v/6.0.0-beta.0), as explained [here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/), you replace `Switch` with `Routes` and you don't need to use `exact` because all `<Route>` paths match *exactly* by default:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <nav style={{ margin: 10 }}>
    <Link to="/" style={{ padding: 5 }}>
      Home
    </Link>
    <Link to="/crime" style={{ padding: 5 }}>
      Crime
    </Link>
  </nav>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<SideBarRight />} />
    <Route path="/crime" element={<Crime />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Also, you don't need to use `BrowserRouter` more than once, so your `SideBarRight` may look like:

```
function SideBarRight() {
  return (
    <div className="content_sidebar">
      <div className="header">
        <span>Computerbar1</span>
      </div>
      {/* <BrowserRouter> -> NOT REQUIRED */}
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Clear</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/crime">Crime</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      {/* </BrowserRouter> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But i tought you dont use switch in v6?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `exact` to your `Route` like this

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<SideBarRight />} />
<Route path="/crime" element={<Crime />} />
```

The reason being `"/"` and `"/crime"` both starts with `/`, and without the `exact` keyword, React thinks they are both the same path.

EDIT: More information on `exact` here https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: So that could be the reason for it to not work at all? Lemme try in an hour :)

Comment: still dont work. clicking on links dont do anything.

Answer (score 0):

First, I guess you are using React router V6 version here, if it was the stable V5 version, above solutions using `<Switch>`, 'exact' would work absolutely fine.

The errors I see in your code are:

1. In GameComponent enclose the `<Route>` paths using `<Routes>` as follows, otherwise '/' will match both '/' and '/crime'

```
      <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<SideBarRight />} />
           <Route path="/crime" element={<Crime />} />
      </Routes>
```

2. Remove `<BrowserRouter>` from `<SideBarRight>` component, it should be added only once for the application

Comment: reach im trying to use react router v6, but it wont update anything , but no errors.  would your code works good? the rotuter from sidebarright is just a test app. its the parent im trying to add it to.'

Comment: It is working for me, please refer to this code sandox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-view-not-updating-issue-forked-tlq6v